# servername prefix added in link

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I noticed that .net/javascript adding up "servername" to all the dynamic URLs.

Googling results up to add `"http"` / `"https"` before the URL string. but I can't do that. As it can be a URL of logfile, to some other pages of the site.

Here is what I am trying to achieve : -

```
$("#someid").html("<a href='" + myURL + "' target='_blank' class='myclass'>" + myURL+ "</a>");
```

now if myURL= `"\\\logfile\mylog.txt"`

then the link which I am getting is : -

```
"servername:8080/\\\logfile\mylog.txt"
```

How to remove servername from this.

Comment: What happens if you delete the trailing "\"?

Comment: In urls, you should use '/', not '\' even its working on windows environment

Comment: well I don't want "servername:port" as sometimes servername is "localhost" and some times when running in production environment, it use to be "domainname.com/applicationurl/\\logfile\mylog.txt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
var host = location.host;
$("a").each(function() {

    $(this).href.replace( host, "" );

});
```

I never really use jQuery, so maybe some syntax is incorrect, but you'll get the idea no?

Comment: slight modification : instead of using $.each, I used following : - $("#someid").html("<a href='" + myURL.replace('\','/') + "' target='_blank' class='myclass'>" + myURL+ "</a>");

Answer (score 0):

Do not use backslashes in URLs - it is Windows only thing, and even then it does not really work. Web standard is to use forward slashes only.

Provided that your server can serve URL like `http://domainname.com/appname/logfile/mylog.txt`, you can use short URL like this:

```
<a href="/appname/logfile/mylog.txt"> See mylog.txt </a>
```

You can also make URL that is relative to your script location a server (suppose in `/appname`) by using relative URL (without leading `/appname`):

```
<a href="logfile/mylog.txt"> See mylog.txt </a>
```